# How probability relates to weather forecasting

Tags: probability

I need to do a mathematics exploration and I've stumbled on a topic that caught my eye, namely probability. I've googled how probability is used in daily life and one of the application is weather forecasting. However, I can't seem to find the relation between both. Anybody mind to explain?

Comment: http://setosa.io/ev/markov-chains/